# How to print the next line from a text file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, loops

I am trying to print two lines of text from a text file in python which are next to eachother on a separate line. So the text file looks like this:

```
Apples
Oranges
Pears
Lemons
```

And if someone inputs Apples I would like the program to print out:

```
Apples
Oranges
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
file = open('Fruit.txt',"r")
for line in file:
    if InputText in line:
        print(line)
        print(line+1)
        return
file.close()
```

Of course the variable `line+1` isn't correct but I have left it there to illustrate that the next line of text must also be printed.

Comment: If your code appears in a function, you should make that clear in your example you give. Otherwise, `return` is illegal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your line matches you can call `next(input)` to generate the following line.
Also if you use the `with` context manager, you remove the need to close the file and this will clean up the code a little bit

```
InputText = 'Pears'

with open('Fruit.txt', "r") as input:
    for line in input:
        if InputText in line:
           print(line, end='')
           print(next(input), end='')
           break

>> Pears
>> Lemons
```

Or with your original solution:

```
InputText = 'Apples'

infile = open('Fruit.txt',"r")
for line in infile:
    if InputText in line:
        print(line, end='')
        print(next(infile), end='')
        return
infile.close()

>> Apples
>> Oranges
```

Comment: A more robust way is `next(input)`.

Comment: When I Use your suggestion I get the error: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not an iterator

Comment: @RipseedOil rename your variable that you've named `file` to `infile` and make sure you call `next(infile)` - see updates

Comment: @RipseedOil. Are you using Python 3 or Python 2 with `from __future__ import print_function`?

Comment: @Mad Physicist I'm using Python 3.4

Comment: Don't forget to `break` out of the loop!

Comment: I was going to update this with your end='' and break but I'll just upvote your answer

Comment: @AK47 Your suggestion worked! Thank You. If I wanted to print the next line from the file, so that three words were printed, could I use next(next(infile))?

Comment: just call `next(infile)` again on the next line, each time you call `next(infile)` it will read the next line of the file. No need to do `next(next())`

Comment: @AK47 Could you explain that further please.

Comment: @AK47. Go ahead and fix up your answer. I think it is actually the better one. I was honestly just point "accumulating". SO won't let me use the word that starts with a "w".

Comment: @RipseedOil. `print(next(file)); print(next(file))` is the way to print two lines. If you want to skip the immediate next one, `next(file); print(next(file))` will do it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist At this point, isn't using `list.index()` not easier? Personally, using `next` twice doesn't quite seem the best way to go...

Comment: @JoeIddon. There are better ways to iterate, yes, but I generally make a habit of iterating as lazily as I can. Loading a small file in its entirety is fine, but you have to keep in mind that these toy examples often represent a search in a file that is millions of lines long.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I see, so are you saying that `next()` is more efficient as it doesn't have to search the entire `file`...

Comment: @JoeIddon. It doesn't require you to load the entire file, yes. Only the lines that you have checked. Actually, your best overall option might be to just use `itertools.islice` at that point. It will ensure that things will be handled correctly even if the file ends early, etc.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things that you should consider changing in your code to make it work properly. Starting from the top:

1. Consider using the file you open as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) in a [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement. To quote the [explanation in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

   > It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point. Using `with` is also much shorter than writing equivalent `try-finally` blocks.
2. The file object you are iterating over is an iterator (who'da thunk it?). That means that you can apply the builtin [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function to it. This will work even if you do not break out of the loop because of the lazy iteration that file objects do. In general, unless you really know what you are doing, calling `next` on the iterator within a `for` loop may cause very unexpected results.
3. Each line (except possibly the last) will contain a trailing `\n` character. [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) normally appends another newline to the strings that it prints. To avoid the double newline, you can add `end=''` to the arguments of `print`. `end` is a keyword-only argument that determines the line ending that `print` appends to its output.
4. You need to clarify what you want to happen when the user enters the word on the last line of the file: `'Lemons'` in your example. At the moment, using `next` will raise a [`StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) error. You can catch the error, transform it, or just add a blank line to the end of the file to make sure it does not happen.
5. The use of [`return`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=return%20statement#defining-functions) is illegal in a module-level loop. If your code is not in a function or method, you should use [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=return%20statement#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) to get out of the loop instead of [`return`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#return).

Here is what all that looks like in combination:

```
with open('Fruit.txt',"r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if InputText in line:
            print(line, end='')
            print(next(file), end='')
            break
```

Comment: Great in-depth answer! Wouldn't calling `line.strip()` be cleaner than `end=''`?

Comment: @JoeIddon. It really depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Joelddon: `line.strip()` creates a new string that you don't need, but it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski. Technically, I think `print` is going to create a new string anyway, but yes, you do technically save a tiny bit of memory this way.

Comment: One thing to consider is what happens if `InputText` matches the last line of the file.  The call to `next(file)` will raise `StopIteration`. That can avoided with `next(file, "some sensible default")` or caught by putting it in a try-except clause.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski. Added a point for that. As I mentioned in my [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410190/how-to-print-the-next-line-from-a-text-file-python/46410587?noredirect=1#comment79779211_46410276), the most general option is probably to use `itertools.islice` after printing the matching `line`. That will most likely handle all the corner cases for you.