# Python looping text file to find and print

Tags: python, python-2.7

This Python code runs but prints the last page of the text file. Not sure why, but I aim to print the whole line of text that is underneath a specified line of text (a line that contains the specific string ** Direct **). How can I loop through a text file, search each line for the specified string, and whenever it is found print the row directly below it? I have searched many online forums and have not found an easily understandable example. I use Python Sypder 2.7. Any help appreciated

```
import os
Path = '..\\Test.txt'

if os.path.isfile(Path): 
    with open(Path) as f:
        for line in f:
            print line
else:
    print Path, "doesn't exist"
f.close()
```

Comment: What string are you searching for?

Comment: Please check if this solution on SO helps! - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410190/how-to-print-the-next-line-from-a-text-file-python

Comment: The string is one line directly underneath the specified string. That string is a number, and that number changes as the text file proceeds, For example, the first instance might be 20, the next 30, the next 40 etc. But each falls one line directly below the specified string

Comment: @Nui okay this sounds totally different than the answers being posted below. What is the `specified` string below to which the `number string` to be searched falls?

Comment: @Nui I have edited my answer according to your requirements in the comment!

Comment: When I line is found containing the string ** Direct **, then the very next line has to be printed (which will be as mentioned some number)

Comment: @Nui you may replace `Anday Wala Burger` in my answer with `Direct` and it should work as expected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Python 3.x:**

dummy.txt

```
Mango
Anday Wala Burger
40
Aloo
Anday
Ghobi
Anday Wala Burger
30
Kheerey
Anday Wala Burger
```

py:

```
searchString = 'Anday Wala Burger'    
with open('dummy.txt', "r") as input:
    try:
        for line in input:
            if searchString in line:
                print(next(input), end='')
    except StopIteration:
            pass
```

OUTPUT:

```
40
30
```

EDIT:

**Python 2.7:**

```
dummyFile= "dummy.txt"
searchString = 'Anday Wala Burger'

with open(dummyFile) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# you may also want to remove empty lines
content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]

# flag
nextLine = False

for line in content:

    if searchString in line:
        nextLine = not nextLine
    else:
        if nextLine:
            print(line)
            nextLine = not nextLine
        else:
            pass
```

OUTPUT:

```
40
30
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187520/discussion-on-answer-by-user5173426-python-looping-text-file-to-find-and-print).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module. It includes the `re.search()` function, which searches for a pattern inside a string.

To print the next line you can take advantage of the fact that file objects are iterable, by using `f.next()`.

For example, you could do:

```
import os
import re

Path = 'foo.txt'
Pattern = "spam"  # String to be searched

if os.path.isfile(Path): 
    with open(Path) as f:
        for line in f:
            if re.search(Pattern, line):
                print(f.next())
else:
    print(Path, "doesn't exist")
```

By the way, you don't need that final `f.close()`. It is already taken care of by the `with` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `one` is in any line in the file and the print the next line as found will be the next lineno file will be set as `currentlineno+1`

Contents of file temp

```
one
two
three
four
```

Python file

```
with open('temp') as f:
   found=-1 
   #no lines are found to print so found is negative in value since line no in a file cannot be negative
   for index,line in enumerate(f):
        if found==index:
            print(line)
        if 'one' in line:
            found=index+1
            # when the condition is True found is set to the line no that we need to print
```

Output

```
two
```

Comment: Works nicely Paul!

Comment: Paul why is found=-1 firstly defined? And is index a built in Python term (hence no need to define it upfront)?

Comment: @Nui It is defined because I check the index or lineno of the file to be equal to found so found must be defined to check else it show the error referenced before assignment .

Comment: Index in Python seems generic and starts from 0. When you use it with enumerate, the 'index' is the 'value' part of enumerate right? Your code runs the same way without found =-1

Comment: @ Albin Paul could you please add some annotation/comments to the 'found=-1' and found lines in the respective if lines?

Comment: @Nui It does not run the same way as you expect, just swap one and two in the about file `temp` and remove `found=-1` from python file , It will show the error I talked about

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes:

1.-Read the lines

2.- Compare with your text

```
import os
Path = '..\\Test.txt'
look='**Direct**'

if os.path.isfile(Path): 
    with open(Path, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if look in line:
                print (line)
else:
    print (Path, "doesn't exist")
```

Comment: Thankyou. This worked but I actually needed the line directly underneath the specified look text. I think @Albin Paul has it with the 'index +1'